# Git how to make commit history identical with remote upstream for master branch

Tags: git

So I my master branch locally is identical in content to the master on my upstream, but the commit history is different, I would like to just make the commit history identical to the one on the upstream is this possible ?

Comment: Why would the content be identical but the commit history different? Regardless, if the content is identical, then there is no risk of data loss. You can do a hard reset and pull.

Comment: @Strikegently I can imagine such a scenario. You download a zip of the source code and create a new repo from it, or something? But yes, what you say is exactly correct. If it's the same and you don't care about your history, just hard reset and pull, or make a brand new clone.

Comment: I'll second a new clone since that's the quickest, easiest method.

Comment: @Strikegently that can be easily reproducible. Just revert last commit. COntent will be just like HEAD~2 but history won't be the same.

Comment: The reason the commit history is different is because whenever I pull in changes from upstream it always add an unnecessary commit that says from so and so.

Comment: @Strikegently: one also gets this when using the GitHub "rebase and merge" or "squash and merge" buttons for pull requests. Whoever made the pull request has to abandon their original commit(s) in favor of the one(s) the person who did the merge just created with the GitHub button. (Well, *has to* implies some sort of absolute requirement, which isn't true, but if you're the person who made the PR, keeping your original commits makes further work more difficult and annoying. It's more *useful* to you, to abandon yours in favor of theirs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the history to be exactly the same, then just do a hard reset on your branch to the remote branch.

```
git checkout my-branch
git reset --hard origin/my-branch
```

That should be enough

Comment: I have some untracked files that I would like to keep would this keep them ?

Comment: git won't mess with the untracked files if they have always been untracked.